# Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokeHelper

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Spring Boot Project

I'm using gradle 5.2.1 I can't change the version because I'm working on someone else's code. When I build the project in IntelliJ I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokeHelper
```

I'm using IntelliJ terminal in my code folder with command ./gradlew clean build install.

when I check ./gradle -version it shows JVM: 16.0.2

I feel the problem is with my jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

As per compatibility [matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#:%7E:text=Table%201.%20Java%20Compatibility%20%20%20Java%20version,%20%207.0%20%205%20more%20rows%20) , only gradle versions of 7 are supporting java 16.
May be you can use older version of jdk which is supporting your current gradle.

Comment: how can I change to an older version of jdk? in IntelliJ when I check the settings my sdk is cornetto 1.8

Comment: But in the IntelliJ terminal when I check gradle version, it shows jvm as 16. IDK why. In my build.gradle file I have mentioned sourceCompatability and targetCompatibility as 1.8

Comment: Can you try using any terminal / bash / command prompt & try to run & see if same error is being thrown. Because error is straight forward i.e. version compatibility of gradle & jdk

Comment: I’m not sure if I can do that. Like the code I’m working with is cloned from a repository and I’m not sure if there’s a main thread cause I’ve cloned a project of a bigger code. I’m trying to build the gradle on IntelliJ so I can make changes and add classes.